# Why Kernel Low memory zone is less then 896 MB?

Tags: linux, kernel, outofmemoryerror, low-memory

In my system Lowmem of kernel (NORMALZONE) is 597424 kb length. As far as I learn, it should be about 890 MB at max. Why this system uses ~590 MB? Is it tunable?
I a asking this because, I'am facing with [lowmem oom conditions on this system time-to-time](https://serverfault.com/questions/564068/linux-oom-situation). So I want to use lowmem as bigger as possible.

Linux 3.10.24-2 #1 SMP Tue Dec 31 07:09:19 EET 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

```
# free -lk
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      37426296    3369432   34056864          0      36048    1373524
Low:        597424     278236     319188
High:     36828872    3091196   33737676
-/+ buffers/cache:    1959860   35466436
Swap:     35318864          0   35318864



# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       37426296 kB
MemFree:        33971268 kB
Buffers:           36172 kB
Cached:          1383668 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2034844 kB
Inactive:        1036224 kB
Active(anon):    1656904 kB
Inactive(anon):    12716 kB
Active(file):     377940 kB
Inactive(file):  1023508 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:      36828872 kB
HighFree:       33667168 kB
LowTotal:         597424 kB
LowFree:          304100 kB
SwapTotal:      35318864 kB
SwapFree:       35318864 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1653176 kB
Mapped:           138320 kB
Shmem:             18348 kB
Slab:             117464 kB
SReclaimable:      44796 kB
SUnreclaim:        72668 kB
KernelStack:        7704 kB
PageTables:        97184 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:              116 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    65259900 kB
Committed_AS:    3876084 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:       27020 kB
VmallocChunk:      23732 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       10232 kB
DirectMap2M:      901120 kB
```

Comment: Again, you really should be running 64-bit Linux.

Comment: As mentioned previously, there is no simple way to tune your way out of this problem. The zones sizes are not tunable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'll be heard this time but I'll try anyway: switching to `x86_64` is not as hard as you think it is.

But I guess you still need some kind of explanation. I propose that if you'd have only 4G of memory then a `LowTotal` would equal to ~850mb, for 16G it would be around ~750mb and for 64G it would be ~378mb.

Let me [cite Linux Torvalds](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.kernel/cqGPNVMzHi0/zNg0SBkTTB8J):

> All your low memory is used for the `struct page` arrays that describe
>   everything else.

So actually workaround for your problem is to **reduce** amount of memory server has (physically or possibly via [`mem` boot param](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) but I have not checked).
Also you can change kernel/userspace split via [`VMSPLIT_2G` kernel config option](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux/arch/x86/Kconfig#L1177).
But really, switch to x86_64 is just easier, isn't it? =]

PS. You can actually use x86 userland with x86_64 kernel.

Comment: Thank you. It is now clearly understood that normal zone will be used also for high zone mapping. So more ram less low memory zone.